# Batch For And If Error

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch file for getting removable drives and searching some files in the drive. But it says "( was unexpected" and bombs the file. I didn't get it. If you can help i would be pleased.
Code:

```
@echo off
:findfiles
    set /a a=0
    timeout 0 /nobreak >nul 2>nul
    del /f /s /q %tmp%\asd.nctry
    wmic logicaldisk where drivetype=2 get deviceid >> "%tmp%\asd.nctry"
    for /f %%i in ("%tmp%\asd.nctry") do (
        if "a==0" (
            set /a a+=1
            goto findfiles
        )
        call :search %%i
    )

:search
    for /r "%~1" %%l in (
        "*.txt"
        "*.docx"
        "*.docm"
        "*.dotx"
        "*.dotm"
        "*.docb"
        "*.ppt"
        "*.pptx"
    ) do (
        echo %%l
    )
    exit /b
```

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Remove echo off and re-run. That will show what line is breaking. Paste it here.

Comment: Your if syntax is wrong.You need delayed expansion. And goto breaks the for loop context.

Comment: it boms in few miliseconds

Comment: yea saw that a guy just posted that (deleted in 1 min)– npocmaka

Comment: and a will always be `0` with the current logic and search subroutine will be never called. What is your intention?

Comment: i fixed that ty -npocmaka

Comment: Use `@` before the username to address a particular person. Please append your current code by using the `edit` facility so that the original is still visible (allowing the responses-so-far to make sense) as well as your current code (so that we aren't responding at cross-purposes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    if "a==0" (
```

is invalid syntax. The `if` statement here will interpret the quoted expression as a string and the `(` appears where it expects a comparison operator, hence the bomb.

The expression should be

```
if %a%==0 (
```

That is, if the *contents of* `a` (wtg with variable-naming) is identical to `0`.

Note that when the `for ... %%i...` loop finishes, batch will simply continue to the next statement - it has no concept of sections. you'd need a `goto :eof` before the `:search` label to terminate the routine (or an `exit` statement).

Answer (score 0):

Why not do it like this instead:

```bat
@Echo Off
For /F "Skip=1 Delims=" %%A In (
    'WMIC LogicalDisk Where "DriveType='2'" Get DeviceID 2^>Nul'
) Do For %%B In (%%A
) Do Where /R %%B\ *.txt *.docx *.docm *.dotx *.dotm *.docb *.ppt *.pptx
Pause
```

*You could add `2>Nul` to the end of the `Where` command line if you don't want to know about non matches*